# Group By using column of foreign key table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a class Transaction :

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
 Driver = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='Driver')
 Passenger = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='Passenger')
 DriverRoute = models.ForeignKey(ServiceProviderRouteDetails)
 PassengerRoute = models.ForeignKey(PassengerRouteDetails)
 Status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Then I have a class TransactionHistory :

```
class TransactionHistory(models.Model):
 Transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transcation)
 User = models.ForeignKey(User)
 Debit = models.FloatField(null='true')
 Credit = models.FloatField(null='true')
 Status = models.CharField(max_length=25)
 DateOfPayment = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

Transaction History has Transaction column as a foreign key that points to Transaction table.
My Problem is that I want to calculate the sum of debit for every  Driver Route for logged in user. Transaction table can have more than one row for a DriverRoute.

I want to do something like this:

```
TranscationHistory.objects.values('Transcation.DriverRoute.id').filter(User_id=request.user.id,Status='Completed').annotate(sum_score=Sum('Credit'))
```

But it's not working... any guess ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `__` to follow the relationship in django query. This would work for you...

```
 TranscationHistory.objects.values('transaction__driverroute__id')
     .filter(User__id=request.user.id,Status='Completed')
     .annotate(sum_score=Sum('Credit'))
```